# How can I solve the problem "segmentation fault"?

Tags: c, string, initialization

```
int CJSON_CDECL main(void)
{
   printf("Version: %s\n", cJSON_Version());
   create_objects();
   return 0;
}

static void create_objects(void)
{
cJSON *root = NULL;cJSON *fmt = NULL;cJSON *img = NULL;cJSON *thm = NULL;cJSON *fld = NULL;
int i = 0;
const char *strings[7] =
{
"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday","Saturday"
}
}
```

When the `create_objects()` function is called, the error happened:

[image]

Comment: I guess the initialization of  char *string may be wrong?

Comment: The function shown does nothing useful — nothing that it does is visible outside the function.  Have you over-minimized the code?  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.

Comment: when I step into the first line of the function create_objects ，the error happened :Exception has occured,the segmentation default

Comment: The problem must be elsewhere. You need to show a [mcve]. What is `CJSON_CDECL` what is `cJSON`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky: It's a plausible guess that `cJSON` is [cJSON](https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON), listed on the [JSON](https://json.org/) web site as one of the many implementations of a C interface for handling JSON.  But I agree that we should not have to speculate on this.  It is surprising to see the `CJSON_DECL` in the definition of `main()`.

Comment: First, do you understand what `segmentation fault` *means*? If not, did you try to use a search engine to [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) it?

Comment: as others have said, please post the whole code, including telling SO what cJSON is, otherwise your question will get closed very soon

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are right,the code is from https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON   I try to debug it at VSCODE in windows system.The whole code is too large to put here.When I debug the test.c ,the error happened.

Comment: @pm100 he code is from github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON I try to debug it at VSCODE in windows system.The whole code is too large to put here.When I debug the test.c ,the error happened

Comment: @KarlKnechtel  I research it but do not find the soluton to  solve the problem

Comment: how did yo build cjson? Are you using gcc, clang or msvc as the compiler?

Comment: @pm100  I used the cmake https://cmake.org/ to build the cjson (the compile platform is vscode+windows11)

Comment: What compiler?.

Comment: the compiler is gcc

Answer (score 0):

I made some assumptions to get a version, which can be compiled by gcc with `gcc -o test test.c`. While doing so I reformatted the code to make it easier to read (at least for me) and found a missing semicolon after the weekday array, which is necessary to make this program compile.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define cJSON char

static char * cJSON_Version(void)
{
    return "1.0.0";
}

static void create_objects(void)
{
    cJSON *root = NULL;
    cJSON *fmt = NULL;
    cJSON *img = NULL;
    cJSON *thm = NULL;
    cJSON *fld = NULL;

    int i = 0;
    const char *strings[7] =
    {
        "Sunday",
        "Monday",
        "Tuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday",
        "Saturday"
    };
}

int  main(void)
{
    printf("Version: %s\n", cJSON_Version());
    create_objects();
    return 0;
}
```

How could a missing semicolon lead to a SEGFAULT?

The screenshot shows some kind of IDE, which can show a SEGFAULT even with an obvious error in the code. I am close to certain, that this error is not produced by any compiler, but comes from some kind of code-linter or another plugin, which is integrated into the IDE. The SEGFAULT then comes from that plugin, which calls a sub-process to evaluate the code and crashes when it finds a data structure with an improper ending, which is then terminated by the kernel with a signal: "SEGFAULT" and that is then returned into the IDE via that plugin.

Let us wait and see if the semicolon fixes it for the thread author ;)

Comment: And does this reproduce the crash?

Comment: Nice, but this does not really try to answer the question, so is out-of-place as a SO answer...

Comment: I edited my answer and explained further how a missing semicolon could possibly lead to a SEGFAULT, like the one from the screenshot.

Comment: I doubt a rep 9 user's 15 line c program is going to crash an IDE, much more likely is that there is nasty code we cant see

Comment: could be, but the line number of the error could also indicate a stack allocation failure, the last known good position so to say, after which the local variables were unsuccessfully pushed to the stack, which again is invisible in most debuggers by default.

Comment: @MaxC the whole code is from the [https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON] which is too large to put here. I  built the code success and try to debug the test.c file.Then the error happened. the compile platform is VSCODE+windows11

Comment: I would recommend, that you edit your question and add these additional information. I can confirm, that the project works fine when compiled with `gcc`, at least `./cJSON_test` program does. Have you made any modifications to the code? Furthermore I do not have Visual Studio Code or Windows 11 to test it. Maybe someone else can try to reproduce the problem with that.

Comment: @jch007: and before I forget: have you tried adding the semicolon behind the char *strings[7] array (second last line from your code post)?

Comment: @MaxC I add the semicolon behind the array in my  code. And I am trying to fix the problem